# How to configure new RSS value to a process in Linux 3.10?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, virtual-memory, fork

I want to limit the RSS of my python process to 5GB. The python process is running C++ code in every iteration (there are 10000 such iterations) and executing some commands which interact with the C++ code. Since the python `subprocess` uses `fork` under the hood, the kernel is allocating twice the value for every iteration. I have also posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737472/memory-allocation-error-os-fork-how-to-prevent-repetitive-memory-allocation-d) with a detailed explanation of the problem and the steps that I took so far to address it.

I am thinking if I can limit the RSS of the process os that it doesn't hinder with other processes, my code will not crash. I read [here](https://www.atoptool.nl/download/case_leakage.pdf) that limiting the RSS of the process might work. The example given is for Linux2.6, however, I am using Linux3.10 and I am unable to find the `/cgroups` in my system.

How can I restrict RSS of my process?

Comment: Do you have `/sys/fs/cgroup`?

Comment: @AndyDalton: Yes

Comment: You indicated that you had examples that referenced cgroups.  You might be able to apply those examples using the interface exposed in `/sys/fs/cgroup`.